# USB microphone unavailable when Pavucontrol loopback works

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa, microphone, headphones, pavucontrol

I connected a USB microphone and analog headphones to laptop and I'm trying to record voice in Audacity. I want to hear other tracks in Audacity and my voice, so I'm using Pawucontrol. Using pacmd, I found the source and sink indexes and loaded module-loopback which works. However, when the module is loaded, my USB microphone either doesn't appear in Audacity input selection or (if I refreshed the list before loading the module) returns an error that it's unavailable. I have a "pulse" input available (from Pulseaudio installed with Pawucontrol), but when I'm using it, the recorded sound is mixed with tracks which are playing. I'm sure the sound isn't leaking from headphones - it's always loud even if I put them away from microphone, so it definitely records again the track that is playing. How can I fix it? In the past it worked on that computer correctly.

Comment: Please provide your OS & release details; `pulseaudio` is being replaced by `pipewire` & you've provided no clues as to your release, thus we currently don't know what is involved in your software stack.

Comment: I am also interested in the answer. I currently use the workaround where I start the recording, then manually connect audacity in the audio graph to the correct input, and cut the extra audio at the start. It's frustrating that I have to do this every time I click record

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, 64-bit, GNOME 42.9 Wayland. PulseAudio 15.99.1

Comment: Now there's other problem: I can't record with USB microphone in Audacity at all when there are any more tracks playing. When I press record, nothing happens and after a while some totally quiet recording is added to the timeline (only horizontal line, no sound). It works only when I disable overdub or mute other tracks.